# Block in @synchronized

Tags: objective-c, thread-safety, objective-c-blocks

Executing a block inside `@synchronized` seems to negate the lock.

```
- (void)method {
    @synchronized(self) {
        if(ivar == nil) {
            ivar = [myBlock() retain];
        }
    }
}
```

The instance variable `ivar` is not written in any other location.

I've observed that the block `myBlock` sometimes is executed twice in my application.

How can this ever happen? How to avoid this an do a real working lock?

Comment: How do you check that the block’s being executed twice? Have you tried `NSLog()`ing that `ivar` assignment, too? Is it possible that `myBlock()` is being called in another part of your application? Is it possible that you have more than one instance of that class?

Comment: I `NSLog()`ed both in the block and after the `ivar` assignment. At first the log from within the block is printed twice (with some delay) and **after** that the log from after the assignment twice. That class is put into a dictionary right after creating and is never copied.

Comment: Your code looks correct. Since the ivar assignment is happening twice, my best guess is that you have two different instances of your class, each receiving `-method`… or `ivar` is being reset.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I also have a `NSLog()` when this class is created and `myBlock` is passed to the initializer. This code is only executed **once**. So there's only one instance (as it's never copied). `ivar` is a private variable and the only place where it is written is in the the above location (and `dealloc` which is not called).

Comment: Have you placed some breakpoints within your block and around the setting of your ivar yet?

Comment: No, as there are thousands of calls to this, and it only happened seemingly random. But as I answered below, the problem was within the block - and within the same thread making the lock useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lock worked fine as `synchronized` locks only threads, and the same thread was accessing the region twice. The problem was, that `myBlock` executed itself inside under some circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could move the locking inside the block.

Comment: no, as the assignment to ivar should be locked. do you know more about locking vs. blocks?